# How to pass variables for a systemd unit file that calls a php script?

Tags: php, systemd, service, ubuntu-18.04

I am needing to create multiple instances of a systemd service. Is it possible to pass the parameters when starting the service, which would be the params for a php script?

For example, let's say I have a script, `test_systemd.php`, with two parameters, `mod` and `rem` respectively.

The php:

```
<?php
$val = getopt(null, ['mod:','rem:']);
echo $val['mod']."\n";
echo $val['rem']."\n";
echo "\n";

?>
```

If I run that via php, I just do `php test_systemd.php --mod foo --rem bar`

Which would echo out

```
foo
bar
```

According to the systemd docs, I'm supposed to use `Environment=`, but I am unsure of how to do that. Let's say I have a systemd unit file called `test-systemd-params.service`:

```
Description=Systemd Params Test
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/test_systemd.php
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/test-multiple-systemd.log
Environment=???? <--- WHAT GOES HERE?

[Install]
#Start after boot
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't understand what I need tp place here. Is that even possible for the two params (`mod` and `rem`) to be passed when starting an instance of the service?

I found [this](https://opensource.com/article/20/12/multiple-service-instances-systemctl) example, and it has two `Environment` lines, but one of them is a static value! I need **two** dynamic values, like:

`Environment=mod=%i`
`Environmen=rem=%i`

The example snippet looks like:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
Environment=LANG=C <--- STATIC, but need another dynamic
Environment=HTTPD_INSTANCE=%i <--- dynamic, great, but need another
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 710 -p /run/httpd/instance-%i
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown root.apache /run/httpd/instance-%i
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 700 -p /var/lib/httpd/instance-%i
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown apache.apache /var/lib/httpd/instance-%i
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND -f conf/%i.conf
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful -f conf/%i.conf
```

Comment: The example snippet you give refers to [service templates](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Service%20Templates). You can pass only one *variable* this way *It is possible for systemd services to take a single argument via the "service@argument.service" syntax.*

Comment: So I can't have two arguments for the php script?

Answer (score 0):

> According to the systemd docs, I'm supposed to use `Environment=`, but I
> am unsure of how to do that. Let's say I have a systemd unit file
> called `test-systemd-params.service`:

This is an example using `Environment=`

```
Description=Systemd Params Test
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment="MOD=foo" "REM=bar"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/test_systemd.php --mod ${MOD} --rem ${REM}
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/test-multiple-systemd.log

[Install]
#Start after boot
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is not what you are looking because variables are static values.

---

> I found [this](https://opensource.com/article/20/12/multiple-service-instances-systemctl) example, and it has two `Environment` lines, but one of them is a static value! I need **two** dynamic values, like:

The example snippet you give refers to [service templates](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Service%20Templates). You can pass **only one variable** this way. *It is possible for systemd services to take a single argument via the "service@argument.service" syntax.*

Here is an example implementation

```
Description=Systemd Params Test
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment=MOD=%i
Environment=REM=bar
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/test_systemd.php --mod ${MOD} --rem ${REM}
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/test-multiple-systemd.log

[Install]
#Start after boot
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you start the services like this:

```
systemctl start test-systemd-params@foo.service
systemctl start test-systemd-params@bar.service
```

So it's still not exactly what you are looking for, because you still have one static variable.

---

The only way I see *(not tested)* to pass multiple variables would be to use [`EnvironmentFile=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=) directive and separated config files with *dynamic* name using the `@argument` synthax.

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/config/%i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/test_systemd.php --mod ${MOD} --rem ${REM}
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/test-multiple-systemd.log
```

Example config file in `/path/to/config/`, let's say `conf1`:

```
MOD=foo
REM=bar
```

Then you start the services like this:

```
systemctl start test-systemd-params@conf1.service
systemctl start test-systemd-params@conf2.service
...
```